# errors when i try to add db from another server to my solution

Tags: .net, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

I have a classic ASP website I am working to try and convert to .NET- one page at a time. I am using VS2010 for this. The development db is on a network share drive, and when I try to debug my application I recieve an error because the BIOS command limit has been reached, as a result of the db being located on a network share drive. Is there any way I can add the db to my solution I am trying to convert?

For example, I added an App_Data folder, and I tried to add an existing item, but then, b/c I do not have the db mapped to any of my local drives on my computer, i could not add it. Is it possible to add a database that is on a network drive?

Or would i need to create a backup of the dev db, restore it to my local and then add it to my solution from my local machine?

I have tried also to use the server explorer to connect to my db, however when i try to create a new data connection w/ the db on the server, i get an error when i try to test the connection b/c the version of SQL server installed on the db is 2000, and you need 2005 or later.

Thanks

Comment: SQL Server does not like to connect/run a .mdf that is on a different machine.  Mostly it has to do with the way SQL Server locks the mdf file, etc.  Your best bet is to backup/restore the DB to your local machine.

Answer (score 0):

i had a similar problem that was caused by using the new connection wizard,VS automaticaly set the connection string properties to the Mapped drive letter i.e Z:\, for some reason it didnt like it so i had to manualy change it in the settings to the server/share/file, after that it worked fine